# Java 7 and and 8 coexisting on Windows 7 Pro x64 - how to fix running old jar files

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, java

I have a Win7 Pro x64 Box with both JRE 7u80 and 8u60 (both are i586 versions) running since I have two applications that either need the one or the other to run.

I am aware of being able to start JAR-files by calling a batch with the according path to java.exe that's what I tried:

```
start "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" "c:\samplepath\some.jar"
```

(It should be

```
start "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\samplepath\some.jar"
```

according to the documentation, but the -jar switch leads to an error that -jar couldn't be found)

This call does start the application without problems as long as Java 8 isn't installed which leads me to the conclusion it's probably ok.

While Java 8 is installed this call does "nothing" - well, almost. I can see the java process in task manager for a few seconds, then it disappears without a trace, there is no error message or whatsoever.

I even deleted the Java entry from %path% and rebooted, changed the order of the JRE installations, deactivated Java 8 in the Java control panel, no luck. If Java 8 is installed my jar won't run.

Talking to the developer isn't an option since he is no longer available. I am out of ideas here. Can somebody help with what I could try next?

Right now I keep the installation files on the desktop to install and dump Java 8 on demand which is quite a ridiculous and desperate manner to deal with it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### But the -jar switch leads to an error that -jar couldn't be found

Your [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)` syntax is incorrect:

- If there is no `title` and `command` is surrounded by quotes `"..."` (because it contains spaces) then it is misinterpreted as a `title`.
- In your case `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"` is interpreted as the `title` and `-jar` as a command (which of course cannot be found).

Your command should be:

```
start "title" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\samplepath\some.jar"
```

You can use `""` (empty string) as the `title` if you prefer:

```
start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\samplepath\some.jar"
```

---

#### Syntax

> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
> ```
>
> **Key**:
>
> ```
> title       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> path        Starting directory.
> command     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> parameters  The parameters passed to the command.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or
>   just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but
>   depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is
>   omitted.

Source [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: Thanks a lot - final solution is `start /MIN "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -jar "c:\samplepath\some.jar"`. /MIN added to suppress the command window. Job done.